# Display expenses daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly and their sum in linq to sql - Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing a windows phone application that does simple expense tracking.
In my application the user enters the expenses made by Item name, price, comments,and 
date time and the details gets stored in the database.

My table has 4 coloums

1. ItemName(string)
2. Price(double)
3. Comments(String)
4. Date(Datetime)

How do I generate a report of the expenses made by today's date, current week, month and year? And also the total sum of prices for today, current week, month, and year? Below is my data context and currently I can display all the expenses only..Please help...Im new to windows phone programming and linq to sql..

```
   namespace ExpenseTracker
  {
[Table]
public class ExpensesTable
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public string ItemName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public double Price
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public string Notes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public DateTime TodayDate
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

}

and

```
 public IList<ExpensesTable> GetExpensesList()
    {

        IList<ExpensesTable> ExpensesList = null;
        using (ExpensesDataContext Expdb = new    ExpensesDataContext(strConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<ExpensesTable> ExpQuery = from Exp in Expdb.ExpensesInfo select Exp;
            ExpensesList = ExpQuery.ToList();
        }
        return ExpensesList;
    }
```

Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just filter expenses by date range (for week, month, etc):

```
 var query = from e in Expdb.ExpensesInfo 
             where e.Date >= beginDate && e.Date <= endDate
             select e;
```

If you need to count totals:

```
 double total = query.Sum(e => e.Price);
```

For filtering todays expenses:

```
 var beginDate = DateTime.Today;
 var endDate = beginDate.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article http://www.codethinked.com/grouping-linq-aggregates-in-c explaining aggregation and grouping in LINQ.